# Watson Studio Desktop Subscription on Windows x64 - blank startup screen

Tags: startup, watson-studio-desktop

Any suggestion how to fix or better diagnose root cause of startup problem described above?
Can I change some configuration setting (timeout or retry count) to get past this?

fresh installation on
OS: Windows 64-bit
Version: 10.0.19041
CPUs: 4
RAM: 5.9GB
Free RAM: 1.1GB
Percent RAM consumed: 81.7%

Watson studio Logfile points to time out starting "connections" addon,
....
[2020-11-02 08:55:37] [ERROR] process-utils - ERROR starting addons: "connections"
[2020-11-02 08:55:37] [ERROR] launch-mgr - Error start application: Failed to start addons "connections"
[2020-11-02 08:56:18] [INFO] ipc-utils - {"nginx":{"status":"READY FOR USE","retryTimesLeft":3},"connections":{"status":"STARTED","retryTimesLeft":3},"projects":{"status":"STARTED","retryTimesLeft":3}}
...

Connections log shows slow start of connections service (289 seconds, almost 5 min)
...
[2020-11-02 08:56:18] [INFO] start - [[** connections-service **]]: [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application wdp-connect-connection started in 289.317 seconds.

[2020-11-02 08:56:18] [INFO] start - 2 of 2 services ready
[2020-11-02 08:56:18] [INFO] start - Connections service is ready

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you do not have enough memory on your system to properly run Watson Studio Desktop. The minimum RAM requirement is 8GB, although the product performs best on systems with 16GB or more.

Here is a link to the system requirements for WSD:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBFT6_1.1.0/wsd/sysreqs.html